# How to filter duplicates and also eliminate integer values appearing AFTER a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to de dupe the below sample and also filter any numeric values appearing after string example below.

**Sample 1**

```
PRIMENOWTIPS CK4SH8WM
PRIMENOWTIPS JE5EG59G
PRIMENOWTIPS M66SC0B
PRIME NOW MT7DY6XG
PRIMENOWTIPS MA73V8VJ
PRIME NOW MU5YY21L
PRIME NOW MV52V1NP
PRIMENOWMKTP 4Q1LS1Q
PRIMENOWMKTP HU1V32M
MYTAXI 1FJJVA
MY CHRONOTYPE
MY NAIL SALON
MYTAXI 1DCE
MYTAXI 1DCHV
MYTAXI 1JTCNM
```

**output**

```
PRIMENOWTIPS
PRIME NOW
MYTAXI
MY CHRONOTYPE
MY NAIL SALON
```

**sample**

```
  11THAVEAUTO123
  10TO12345
  11BIGJIM12345
  1234556788
  23456
```

**expected output**

```
   11THAVEAUTO
   10TO
   11BIGJIM
```

Comment: You're asking _two_ cleanup questions here, and you haven't given clear words for how we know to identify the content to be removed.

Comment: correct that the challenge i have with this data and was trying to see if some experts have any idea..

Comment: @stackuser do you have any unique identifier for each row?

Comment: Yes I do have unique Identifier for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexp_substr() to do most of the work. Though I am not good at it, I found a solution for both of your dataset. For **sample1** I have added an ID column of int type for further reference.

**First Scenarion:**
First I find out which rows have string with numbers. Then extracted those strings and replaced those with nothing.
Input:

```
  create table test3 (id int, t varchar(1000));
insert into test3 values(1,'PRIMENOWTIPS CK4SH8WM');
insert into test3 values(2,'PRIMENOWTIPS JE5EG59G');
insert into test3 values(3,'PRIMENOWTIPS M66SC0B');
insert into test3 values(4,'PRIME NOW MT7DY6XG');
insert into test3 values(5,'PRIMENOWTIPS MA73V8VJ');
insert into test3 values(6,'PRIME NOW MU5YY21L');
insert into test3 values(7,'PRIME NOW MV52V1NP');
insert into test3 values(8,'PRIMENOWMKTP 4Q1LS1Q');
insert into test3 values(9,'PRIMENOWMKTP HU1V32M');
insert into test3 values(10,'MYTAXI 1FJJVA');
insert into test3 values(11,'MY CHRONOTYPE');
insert into test3 values(12,'MY NAIL SALON');
insert into test3 values(13,'MYTAXI 1DCE');
insert into test3 values(14,'MYTAXI 1DCHV');
insert into test3 values(15,'MYTAXI 1JTCNM');
```

**Solution:**

```
with cte as (    
    select id,regexp_substr(t,'[^" "]+', 1, level)t2 from test3
    connect by regexp_substr(t, '[^" "]+', 1, level) is not null
    ),
cte2 as ( select distinct id,t2 from cte
    where regexp_substr(t2, '[0-9].*') is not null
    )
    select test3.id,test3.t,replace(t,t2,'')as Transformed from test3 inner join cte2 on test3.id=cte2.id
    where regexp_substr(t2, '[0-9].*') is not null
    order by test3.id
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Second Scenarion:**
Input:

```
create table test (t varchar(1000));
  insert into test values('11THAVEAUTO123');
  insert into test values('10TO12345');
  insert into test values('11BIGJIM12345');
  insert into test values('1234556788');
  insert into test values('23456');
```

**Solution:**

```
select t,substr(t,1,instr(t,regexp_substr(t, '[A-Z].[0-9]'))+1)as Transformed  from test
where regexp_substr(t, '[A-Z].[0-9]') is not null;
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Close it failing for these TEXT G93QZ10T, TEXT GE2KJ26S,TEXT GG0QU2KU. The Trailing string is starting with char as opposed to number. any thoughts

Comment: Will try to figure out. What is your desired output from  those?